# How to read data from Controller action redirect?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, routes, controller

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions) show how to redirect to a `controller action`:

```
return redirect()->action(
    [HomeController::class, 'index'], ['id' => 1]
);
```

but how do I read the `id` parameter inside `HomeController`?

These don't seem to work:

1

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
    }
}
```

2

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

3

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Action $id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `HomeController@index` route accept the `id` ?

Comment: your route should be taking a route parameter otherwise `id` is just going to be a query string parameter which you can access from the request inputs: `$request->input('id')` ... if your route took a parameter for `id` you could have it passed to the controller method or via the request: `$request->route('id')`

Comment: @lagbox yes, you were right. I had to use `$request->input(...)` because I tried passing the parameter without route. Now it works. Do you want to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($id);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //Do something

        return redirect()->action(
           [HomeController::class, 'index'], ['id' => 1]
        );
    }
}
```

In `web.php`

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: I am getting `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index(), 1 passed in ... and exactly 2 expected.`

Comment: I modified it , could you check it !

Answer (score 0):

If your route doesn't take a route parameter then calling `action` will append `id` as a query string parameter. This would be an input on the request which you can access via the `Request` object as an input:

```
$request->input('id')
```